# Photoshop: 2024 Want to export selected groups/layers in the layers panel to individual PNGs; But the script only works partially?

Tags: javascript, export, jsx, photoshop, photoshop-script

The *script* I tried works, but it's *only partially accurate* because *it only exports the first two selected layers/groups* in the layer panel as individual PNGs.
Also, *for the script to work* as intended, the *visibility of the selected layers needs to be disabled except for the topmost selected layer.*
*I want all the selected layers to be exported as individual PNGs*. Regardless of their visibility in the layers panel.

**Simply put I want to take a group merge its contents and export as a PNG with transparency then move on to the next group......**

any help would be appreciated!

```
function main() {
    if (!documents.length) return;
    var doc = activeDocument;
    var oldPath = activeDocument.path;

    for (var a = 0; a < doc.layerSets.length; a++) {
        var layerSetName = doc.layerSets[a].name;
        var targetLayer = getLayerByName(layerSetName);

        if (targetLayer) {
            activeDocument.activeLayer = targetLayer;
            duplicateLayer();
            activeDocument.mergeVisibleLayers();

            // Assuming you want to save each group with its name
            var saveFile = new File(oldPath + "/" + layerSetName + ".png");
            SavePNG(saveFile);
        }
    }
}

function SavePNG(saveFile) {
    var pngOpts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb;
    pngOpts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
    pngOpts.PNG8 = false;
    pngOpts.transparency = true;
    pngOpts.interlaced = false;
    pngOpts.quality = 100;
    activeDocument.exportDocument(saveFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, pngOpts);
}

function duplicateLayer() {
    var desc143 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref73 = new ActionReference();
    ref73.putClass(charIDToTypeID('Dcmn'));
    desc143.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref73);
    desc143.putString(charIDToTypeID('Nm  '), activeDocument.activeLayer.name);
    var ref74 = new ActionReference();
    ref74.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt'));
    desc143.putReference(charIDToTypeID('Usng'), ref74);
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID('Mk  '), desc143, DialogModes.NO);
}

function getLayerByName(name) {
    var layers = activeDocument.layers;
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        if (layers[i].name === name) {
            return layers[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

main();
```

Comment: Just so I'm sure I understand your request - you're not working will *all of the main groups*, just those of them that have been selected / marked? The reason I'm asking - in your question, you mention the selected groups, but your code (as far as I can tell) works with all of the main / first-level groups.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not clear at all.
However, the basis of your script is this: You need to loop over ALL layers using a recursive function, then detect if the layer is a group and then merge it before you export it.

```
// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

// group layer vegetables
var theLayers = collectAllLayers(app.activeDocument, 0);


// function collect all layers
function collectAllLayers (theParent, level)
{
   for (var m = theParent.layers.length - 1; m >= 0; m--)
   {
      var theLayer = theParent.layers[m];
      
      // apply the function to layersets;
      if (theLayer.typename == "LayerSet")
      {
        //alert(theLayer.name);
        // make the current layer active
        srcDoc.activeLayer = theLayer;
        merge_group();
        collectAllLayers(theLayer, level + 1)
      }
   }
}



function merge_group()
{
  // =======================================================
  var idMrgtwo = charIDToTypeID( "Mrg2" );
  executeAction( idMrgtwo, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
}
```